# How to set display:block and transition opacity at the same time in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, jsx

I have a background layer element defined in JSX which has set `display:none` intially:

```
<div id="naviBG" style={naviBGStyleClone} role="button" onClick={this.onCloseClicked} />
```

**Style:**

```
const naviBGStyle = {
  display: 'none',
  opacity: 0,
  transition: 'opacity 0.4s ease',
};
```

When clicked, I want the layer to smoothly disappear or re-appear using the transition defined in css. In `render()` I check if the element should be shown or hidden:

**render()**

```
const naviBGStyleClone = Object.assign({}, naviBGStyle);
if (this.props.status === 'closed') {
  naviBGStyleClone.display = 'none';
  naviBGStyleClone.opacity = 0;
} else {
  naviBGStyleClone.display = 'block';
  naviBGStyleClone.opacity = 1;
}

return (
    <div id="naviBG" style={naviBGStyleClone} role="button" onClick={this.onCloseClicked} />
);
```

Now, this kinda works as the element will be shown/hidden but it pops in without the transition animation set on opacity.

Normally I would then use something like `requestAnimationFrame` to work around this like so:

**render() with raf:**

```
const naviBGStyleClone = Object.assign({}, naviBGStyle);
if (this.props.status === 'closed') {
  naviBGStyleClone.display = 'none';
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      naviBGStyleClone.opacity = 0;
    });
  }
} else {
  naviBGStyleClone.display = 'block';
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      naviBGStyleClone.opacity = 1;
    });
  }
}

return (
    <div id="naviBG" style={naviBGStyleClone} role="button" onClick={this.onCloseClicked} />
);
```

But this won't work in react as it would cause the style to be modified after `render()` has already finished.

So, what's the correct way to do this in React?

Comment: the most common way to do this is doing it in two quick steps. set the display to block then on the next loop change the opacity. Is display block even a requirement though? what about changing the zindex instead?

Comment: Yeah, I think it would be nice if the element completely disappears from the render tree using `display:none`. What do you mean by "next loop"?

Comment: Next cycle of the event loop. If you trigger a css transition on an element with display none then the transition doesn't occur. if you set it to block then on the very next round of the event loop trigger the transition then it will happen. This is true with or without react. I can write up an answer with some examples if you want. My above suggestion is not the only way

Comment: @azium That's why I used requestAnimationFrame - Doesn't work

Comment: requestAnimationFrame can be used, just not the way you have it. I'll write up an answer with some working examples

Comment: @azium That would be great as I'm currently stuck at this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because transitions don't trigger on items that are hidden via `display: none`, you can call `setState` twice in a row, once to trigger the display change then again to trigger the opacity change, and the same in the reverse order to make it fade out then hidden.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { display: 'none', opacity: 0 }

  toggle = () => {
    if (this.state.display === 'none') {
      this.setState({ display: 'block' })
      setTimeout(() =>
        this.setState({ opacity: 1 }), 10 // something very short
      )
    }
    if (this.state.display === 'block') {
      this.setState({ opacity: 0 })
      setTimeout(() =>
        this.setState({ display: 'none' }), 300 // same as transition time
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>        
        <div 
          style={{ 
            transition: 'opacity 0.3s ease',
            opacity: this.state.opacity,
            display: this.state.display
          }} 
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/MoKVGP?editors=0010)

I would also encourage you to look at React Motion for handling more intricate transitions like you might do with `requestAnimationFrame`

https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion

Comment: Any reason why you used setTimeout instead of raf?

Comment: it makes no difference if you're only calling the function once. they will both fire on the next available event loop

Comment: Yeah, I'm just asking because setTimeout is bad practice afaik

Comment: You are probably thinking of setInterval, which is bad for animations because it's not called reliably. setTImeout is perfectly fine, particularly if you're calling it once (not for animation) like in my code